# Why doesn't my http POST request go well?

Tags: ruby, post, neo4j

I am trying to make this [POST request](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html#rest-api-create-an-auto-index-for-nodes-with-specific-configuration) in ruby. but get back 
`#<Net::HTTPUnsupportedMediaType:0x007f94d396bb98>` what I tried is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

auto_index_nodes =URI('http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/')

request_nodes = Net::HTTP::Post.new(auto_index_nodes.request_uri)
http = Net::HTTP.new(auto_index_nodes.host, auto_index_nodes.port)

request_nodes.add_field("Accept", "application/json")

request_nodes.set_form_data({"name"=>"node_auto_index",
                            "config" => {
                            "type" => "fulltext",
                            "provider" =>"lucene"} ,
                            "Content-Type" => "application/json"
                            })


response = http.request(request_nodes)
```

Tried to write this part:

```
"config" => {
             "type" => "fulltext",
             provider" =>"lucene"} ,
             "Content-Type" => "application/json"
            }
```

like that:

```
"config" => '{
              "type" => "fulltext",\
              "provider" =>"lucene"},\
              "Content-Type" => "application/json"\
              }'
```

this try didn't help either:

```
request_nodes.set_form_data({"name"=>"node_auto_index",
                            "config" => '{ \
                            "type" : "fulltext",\
                            "provider" : "lucene"}' ,
                            "Content-Type" => "application/json"
                            })
```

Comment: I guess it is related with response of your server here, can you debug what server responds ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "json"

uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/")

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
req['Accept'] = 'application/json'

req.body = {
  "name" => "node_auto_index",
  "config" => { "type" => "fulltext", "provider" => "lucene" },
}.to_json    

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
```

Here's [the API doc and a short introduction to Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)

The `Content-Type` and `Accept` are headers, so you need to send them as headers, not in body. The JSON content should go in request body, but you need to convert your Hash to JSON and not send it as form data in name/value pairs.